# Camera Calibration: Can Wrong Dimension Give Correct Distortion?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

When calibration a camera, one must provide a set of 'world points' (points on the real grid with real world units), and a corresponding set of 'image points'.

My question is: if I were to factor a 'world points' by an arbitrary factor (in other words, give a wrong dimension of the real world units), would I still get a correct values of distortion and principle point (ignoring the obvious wrong values of focal length)?

In other words: will the distortion coefficients and principle I yield stay numerically the same, regardless of the world points scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

It is just like using your own unit of length like millimeters and inches.

The result still makes sense in your own unit.

The principle point should have the same value because it is measured in pixels of the sensor, not depending on the physical length. Also the distortion coeffs should be the same because they are basically the ratios of two metrics.

Comment: Your answer doesn't fully satisfy my question: will the distortion coefficients and principle I yield stay *numerically the same*, or not?